# Why is the Sun's Luminosity not equal to the Zero Point Luminosity?

Tags: the-sun, luminosity

I was doing some research and found that the zero-point luminosity was $L_\odot = 3.75\times 10^{28} $, while the sun's reported luminosity was $L_{Sun} = 3.828\times 10^{26}$, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun). Why isn't it the same value? Doesn't the symbol $\odot$ represent the value of our sun?

Furthermore, when Googling the Luminosity of the sun, it gives $1L_\odot$, which suggests that $L_{Sun} = L_\odot$ when it is evidently not. What's going on here? I'm very confused.

For background, I have little to no background knowledge of astrophysics, and I'm trying to learn about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you link/clarify what the 'zero point luminosity' is? I'm not familiar with the concept myself. Also units should always be added for any physical quantities.

Comment: @Anurag Do you mean the zero point of the absolute magnitude scale?

Comment: $L_{\odot}$ is the bolometric luminosity of the Sun. I don't know where you get $3.75 \times 10^{28}$ W from?

Comment: What units are these two values in? Are they both in Watts? If not, they could be equivalent, but using different unit systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zero point luminosity L<sub>0</sub> is the luminosity of a star whose absolute [bolometric magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_magnitude#Bolometric_magnitude) M<sub>bol</sub> is 0.
[IAU recommends](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.06262) the value
L<sub>0</sub> = 3.0128 × 10<sup>28</sup> W.
If the Sun's M<sub>bol</sub> is +4.74, then
L<sub>0</sub> / L<sub>sun</sub> = 10<sup>4.74 / 2.5</sup> = 78.7,
which is consistent with L<sub>sun</sub> = 3.828 × 10<sup>26</sup> W.

Your understanding that L<sub>sun</sub> ≡ L<sub>☉</sub> is correct.
Maybe there was an accidental substitution of L<sub>☉</sub> for L<sub>0</sub> at some point.
Curiously, the number 3.75 × 10<sup>28</sup> appears in the [Wikipedia:Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun) sidebar as the Sun's luminous flux in *lumens*, a quantity more applicable to a light bulb than to a star.